# Get three-digit numbers where the sum of factorials of the digits equals to the number

Tags: algorithm

I am reading combinatorial book for school and have to do some exercises, this is one of them:

Write a computer program to determine whether there is a three-digit integer `abc (= 100a + 10b + c)` where `abc = a! + b! + c!`.

My attempt is below.

Can someone propose a better (faster) algorithm for this task?

```
int power(int n)
{
    int sum=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        sum*=i;
    }
    return sum;
}

void compute()
{
    int abc;
    int powa,powb,powc;
    for(int a=1;a<100;a++){
        for(int b=1;b<100;b++){
            for(int c=1;c<100;c++){
                abc=(100*a)+(10*b)+c;
                powa=power(a);
                powb=power(b);
                powc=power(c);
                if(abc==(powa+powb+powc)){
                    cout<<"There is ,nums are :"<<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    compute();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide some information about the topic. "Looking for more clever way for this task" is going to be meaningless to a future reader here who finds it in search results. It's always a good idea to also include a tag for the specific language you're using for your code - it helps get the question in front of the people who can answer it more quickly.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Your `power` function should be named `factorial`, and its `sum` variable should be named `product`. If you want your identifiers to align with what the rest of the planet uses ;)

Comment: isn't `a` limited to a single digit?  0-9?  Actually, 7! is 5040, so all three digits are 0-6.  That means there's only 216 combinations to try, you can do that in a heartbeat.

Comment: By looping `a`, `b` and `c` from 1-100 instead of 1-9 (including 0 where appropriate), you're actually solving a different problem than the one you appear to have been asked to solve.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (var n = 0; n < 1000; n++)
{
   var a = (n / 100);
   var b = (n / 10) % 10;
   var c = n % 10;

   var m = a! + b! + c!;

   if (m == n)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(n);
   }
}
```

Maybe start with 100 if you don't want to consider leading zeros. Or this way.

```
for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
   for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++)
   {
      for (var c = 0; c < 10; c++)
      {
         var n = 100 * a + 10 * b + c;
         var m = a! + b! + c!;

         if (m == n)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Again maybe skip zeros if you don't want leading zeros. You may also be able to exit loops early if you determine that `m` will always be larger than `n`. For example `a`, `b` and `c` can not become larger than 6 because 7! is larger than 999.

Comment: You can also pre-table the factorial calculations to avoid recalculating them multiple times, since there are only 10 of interest.

Answer (score 2):

We have 900 possible numbers at the beginning. Observing the rules we can notice the following:

7!, 8! and 9! are bigger than 999, so they cannot be used. This gets us down to 294 possible numbers.

0!, 1!, 2!, 3! and !4 are all smaller than 25. This means that at least one of the three digits you use will have to be five or bigger. This reduces it down to 194 possible numbers.

Now that we've eliminated a big number of cases on paper, we need to check them all. Instead of calculating the factorials all the time we calculate them once for every digit 0-6 and save them in an array.

Then for every combination three digits 0-6 (with the first one being 1) where at least one 
is bigger than 4, we check if it fits the condition a!+b!+c!=a*100+b*10+c.

There might be some additional ways to optimize it, but even this is overkill considering you only have 3 digits (which is a very small number of possible cases).

```
int factorials[7];

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n<2)return n;
    else return n*factorial(n-1);
}

void check(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if((a>4 || b>4 || c>4) && factorials[a]+factorials[b]+factorials[c]==a*100+b*10+c)
    cout<<"There is, nums are : "<<a<<","<<b<<","<<c<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)factorials[i]=factorial(i);
    for(int a=1;a<7;a++)
        for(int b=0;b<7;b++)
            for(int c=0;c<7;c++)check(a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```